# How to quickly determine which process (if any) listens to a serial port.

Tags: linux

I am looking for a command to see the process listening to a port, e.g. `/dev/ttyS0` (with root rights on a Linux system). I can do that with

```
lsof /dev/ttyS0
```

but this is really too slow. Also, I cannot use the `-p` flag to make it faster.

I would like to do essentially the same using other resources of the linux system. Is that possible?

Comment: Try `fuser /dev/ttyS0`. Anyway, if you have a lot of running processes, this operation will be slow because both `fuser` and `lsof` are scanning all `/proc/*/fd/`. Also if you are not root, you won't be able to read a lot of information.

Comment: There is also the fuser command, but likely it does the same thing as lsof and will also be slow

Comment: You could enable auditing: http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/ however this might be some sort of overkill ... ;-)